# OpenCV encounters issue when capturing image from webcam

Tags: c++, opencv

When I try to capture a picture from my webcam using OpenCV, it shows some errors and returns a black picture.

operation system: Windows 10 Insider Preview 10.0.18970.1005

OpenCV version: 4.1.1

the main code:

```cpp
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main() {
    VideoCapture cam;
    while (!cam.open(0))cerr << "failed to open cam" << endl;
    namedWindow("test");
    while (1) {
        Mat img;
        cam >> img;
        imshow("test", img);
        if (waitKey() == 27)break;
    }
    destroyWindow("test");
}
```

the output, which is unexpected and unwanted.

```
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\videoio_registry.cpp (187) cv::`anonymous-namespace'::VideoBackendRegistry::VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Enabled backends(7, sorted by priority): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); MSMF(970); DSHOW(960); CV_IMAGES(950); CV_MJPEG(940)
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (340) cv::impl::getPluginCandidates Found 2 plugin(s) for GSTREAMER
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (172) cv::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load D:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_videoio_gstreamer411_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (172) cv::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_videoio_gstreamer411_64.dll => FAILED
[ WARN:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Comment: Is the DLL present in the directory mentioned in the error message?

Comment: I didn't find a folder named 'build' in the C: directory :(. also, it seems that opencv_python meets the same error, which led to a blank picture. But the camera is working well.

Comment: The folder you have to look in is "D:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc15\bin\", check if the file "opencv_videoio_gstreamer411_64.dll" is present in this folder. Then read the error message again from start to end.

Comment: OK, it seems that the .dll file isn't present. Maybe this is the error. Thanks a lot. But I don't quite get how to fix this......

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem. I am using the Windows 10 system, and finally found that I banned the use of the camera. **Please check the permissions of the camera in the privacy settings.**